"Class phpunit cannot be found" after upgrading to PHP >=8
I am trying to upgrade our PHP version from 7.4 to >=8.0 on our corporate website which runs on WordPress.
Prior to making this version change, our PHPUnit tests run perfectly fine. Upgrading the PHP version now results in the following error:
Class phpunit cannot be found in /usr/src/wordpress/wp-content/themes/company-website/vendor/bin/phpunit

When executing ./vendor/bin/phpunit --version, I see the following which leads me to think that Composer is in fact installing PHPUnit correctly:
PHPUnit 11.1.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Is there something that changed as part of PHP >=8.0 that requires me to install/configure PHPUnit differently? I'm not sure why it suddenly can't find the phpunit class. I should note that I get this error both with our existing PHPUnit version (9.6.19) as well as a newer version which I am trying to update to (11.1.3) while on PHP >=8.0.
For context in terms of what changes I made, I have a PR with the following changes. Comments represent lines that were updated in the files.

Dockerfile
# FROM wordpress:php7.4-apache as wordpress

FROM wordpress:php8.2-apache as wordpress

...
    
# pecl install xdebug-3.1.0 && \

pecl install xdebug-3.3.2 && \

...

# curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer --version=2.2.7

curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer --version=2.7.4

drone.Dockerfile
# FROM wordpress:php7.4-apache as wordpress

FROM wordpress:php8.2-apache as wordpress

...

# curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer --version=2.2.7

curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer --version=2.7.4

docker-compose.yml
 # composer:
  #  image: composer:2.2.7

  composer:
    image: composer:2.7.4

...

  # phpcs:
   # image: php:7.3-cli

  phpcs:
    image: php:8.2-cli

...

  # phpcbf:
   # image: php:7.3-cli

  phpcbf:
    image: php:8.2-cli

composer.json (composer.lock was updated as part of these changes)
// "require-dev": {
//   "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
// }

"require-dev": {
   "phpunit/phpunit": "^11.1",
} 

run-phpunit.sh looks like this (we run the tests with this shell script)
./vendor/bin/phpunit --version
./vendor/bin/phpunit --no-configuration --coverage-clover coverage/clover.xml --coverage-filter _includes/ --testdox tests


According to https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/references/phpunit-compatibility-and-wordpress-versions/ Wordpress supports only up to PHPUnit major version 9. I also had similar errors when using PHPUnit 10 or 11. I had to downgrade to PHPUnit 9.6 and it worked. PHPUnit 9.6 does support PHP8

@AaylaSecura Thanks for your thoughts! As per my post, "I should note that I get this error both with our existing PHPUnit version (9.6.19) as well as a newer version which I am trying to update to (11.1.3) while on PHP >=8.0". I think there's something else happening here.

Oh, apologies, I missed that point in your post! I can't seem to reproduce this error based on the partial Dockerfile. If I install only what's shown, from scratch (wordpress:php8.2-apache with composer and phpunit v11.1.3) and run a sample test file, it runs ok. Might be worth creating a clean basic image like that and then adding the remaining things one by one, checking after each step. It's not clear to me how the two docker files (Dockerfile and drone.Dockerfile) relate and how the images are composed together. Might also be worth posting the full docker configs.
